# Fancyhead \rightmark not updating

Tags: fancyhdr

I have suddenly got an issue with fancyhead{\rightmark} not updating to the current chapter/section, cannot figure out what is wrong, see code below, \rightmark is empty for Chapter 1:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{xthesis}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=red,breaklinks = true, 
%urlcolor = blue, pdftitle={Report}, pdfauthor={Author}]{hyperref}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{} 
\fancyhead[L]{}

\begin{document}

%\cleardoublepage \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
%\listoffigures


\chapter*{Introduction \label{cha:Introduction}}

\newpage
\fancyhead[R]{Aims}
\section*{Aim of this Thesis \label{sec:Aim}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Aim of this Thesis}
    The aims of this thesis are:


\cleardoublepage

\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: Image of Output]

Comment: Please make your your example is self contained, ``xthesis` is not a known package.

Comment: Have edited out the use of xthesis package and problem still persists

Comment: `\section*` doesn't set the `\rightmark`, only `\section` does. You can add it with `\markright{Aim of this Thesis}` after the `\section*` command. But then the following `\chapter` sets the `\leftmark` and clears the `\rightmark`.

Comment: Thanks @Pieter, the problem isn't in fact replicated after taking out xthesis like I thought, so must be an issue with that package.

Comment: As Pieter says `\chapter` sets `\rightmark` to be empty, so that is what you see, no output. Try adding `\leftmark` instead. And you should not use `\fancyhead[R]{Aims}`, use instead `\markboth{Aims}{Aims}`

Answer (score 2):

You might set the right and the left marks for the un-number section using `\markboth{Introduction}{Aim of this Thesis}`.

But then also choose the `twoside` option for the `report` to keep the numbered chapter with the same style.

**From** `\chapter*{Introduction}`

[image: a]
[image: b]

**From** `\chapter{First Chapter}`
[image: c]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}} % section
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} %chapter
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}

%\cleardoublepage \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
%\listoffigures

\chapter*{Introduction \label{cha:Introduction}}
1.  \kant[1]

\markboth{Introduction}{Aim of this Thesis} % <<<<<<<<<<<
\section*{Aim of this Thesis \label{sec:Aim}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Aim of this Thesis}

The aims of this thesis are:

2   \kant[2-6]  

\chapter{First Chapter}
3.  \kant[3-9]

\section{Numbered section}
4,  \kant[4-8]

\end{document}
```